# Google App Engine: how to speed up database query on a short-string property?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a quite simple database query:

```
Query q = new Query("person");
q.addFilter("name", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, req.getParameter("n"));
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
for (Entity result : pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults())) {
// ...
}
```

So it's simple search all entries for the given name. The name isn't unique and contains maximal 16 characters. As far as I know the index for the short strings (<500 characters) is generated automatically.

In the table are about 100000 entries. The database request needs more than 8 seconds to fetch all (about 10) entities.

The question is now how to speed it up?

Comment: How big are these entities in total?

Comment: The entities are quite small. In total: 3 Integer, 1 String and 1 Date.

Comment: Is this in production or on the dev appserver in the sdk?

Comment: I have just run it on the dev-appserver in the sdk, started with eclipse (google-plugin). Do you think it would preform on the production server in a few milliseconds?

Comment: why don't you try, it could be better, the local implementation is totally different from the production one.

Comment: I didn't know that there is so a big difference between the production and develop server. I will try it and then share my results. I hope it's the solution.

Comment: In terms of performance, there is a big difference between the development and production environments. Don't worry about performance when in the dev environment, worry instead about correctness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dev appserver's performance is not indicative of production performance. In particular, the dev appserver does not use indexes. *At all*. Every query just scans every entity of that type.

So don't insert that much data into the dev appserver. Use it to test basic functionality, then deploy, and insert your 1000000 entities into the production app engine appserver instead, where indexes actually get generated and used.

Comment: There's also the option of having a test version of your application (technically a separate application) that you deploy to for performance testing.